# CSS ellipsis on first column in two column layout

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a row that contains two blocks of text. I want to show them side by side in such a way that:

- First block aligns with left corner and truncates if necessary
- Second block aligns with right corner and displays completely
- Text must stay on one line
- **Source order cannot be changed**
- **Cannot assign fixed widths to any of those blocks**
- **<del>Support IE8</del>**

Here is my markup:

```html
<div style="background: #FC0; width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">
    <span style="background: #CF0; float: left;">Icicle River, Leavenworth, Washington, USA</span>
    <span style="background: #F0C; float: right;">$1,000-$9,999</span>
</div>
```

And the expected output

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|Icicle River, Leavenworth, Washingto... $1,000-$9,999|
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

I have had success when I rearranged the columns (number first, area second) and added floats and overflows. However, I am not allowed to change the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible using flexbox. The layout will be broken in browsers that don't support flexbox but in those cases you might be able to implement some fallbacks to at least make the result presentable.

```css
.container {
    background: #FC0;
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
}
.left {
    background: #CF0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1%;
}
.right {
    background: #F0C;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="left">Icicle River, Leavenworth, Washington, USA</span>
    <span class="right">$1,000-$9,999</span>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pr7dmj8z/2/

Comment: Thanks, adding `width: 100%` did the trick for me